# Work with dir from www-user and from console in Mac OS x

Tags: macos, symfony, console, chmod

I install Symfony and do:

```
chmod -R 777 app/cache app/log
```

Open from browser - all works great! When go to console and do:

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

and get error what i have not primission to delete file. Ok, i l'll do it with sudo:

```
sudo php app/console cache:clear
```

Great! But...

In browser i get:

```
RuntimeException: Failed to write cache file
```

Please

Comment: Make sure that you are running your web-server from the same user as you are.

Comment: Which web-server do you actually use? **Apache** or **nginx**? If apache, which one - was it "in box" or you installed it via mac-ports?

Comment: See my answer on your same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702888/work-with-app-console-in-symfony-at-mac-os-x

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should do 2 things:

1. Make sure that you are running you web-server from the same user as you are.
2. Change owner or permission to the directory, in which your project is stored.

I'll explain point 2 little deeply.

Usually you create projects in `/var/www` folder. So, `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www` would fix your issue.

P.S. Next time you should provide more details on your configuration setup. At least, some `ls -l` and `pwd` would help us to give you proper answer faster.

Cheers ;)